# Why is the partition marked as "boot" empty?

Tags: linux, boot, grub

After installing Ubuntu 20.04, I have the following partition layout:

```
sda      8:0    0 120,9G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part 
└─sda5   8:5    0 120,4G  0 part /
```

If I issue `sudo ls -a /boot/efi`, I see no files. So it seems that sda1 is empty.

Isn't this partition (sda1) the entry point for the BIOS/UEFI during the boot process?

In how far is the partition useful and how is GRUB located at */boot* (on sda5) involved?

Comment: Does your computer boot from the disk with Ubuntu 20.04 installed on it? If so, the partition can't be empty because it requires files in order to boot. You might not be able to read from the partition despite using ```sudo```.

Comment: @Todd after trying a few things out on vbox I realized that the boot partition only has MBR or GPT info which points to /boot directory which is directly on my linux partition (no extra partition). And that's the problem. I want to encrypt my complete partition using LUKS. So, whats in /boot directory right now needs to be on the boot partition. I figured out how to do that now.